# twilio mute not working outging calls

Tags: twilio, twilio-php, twilio-api

I am using

```
function call() {
    // get the phone number to connect the call to
    params = {"PhoneNumber": $("#number").val()};
    Twilio.Device.connect(params);
}
```

to make a call and

```
function mute() {
    connection.mute(true);
}
```

to mute a call.

This works for incoming call but does not work for outgoing calls.

Can anyone assist?

Comment: How are you getting the `connection` object in the `mute` function?

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same issue working on outgoing calls.

What worked for me was naming the connection, and then muting that.

For example:

```
var connection = Twilio.Device.connect(params);

function mute() {
    connection.mute(true);
}
```

Before when it wasn't named, it didn't work. Setting it to the connection variable got it working for me.

Hope that helps!